# Checking if an array contains exactly a specific set of integers

Tags: javascript

Is that possible to check if the variable array contains exactly the numbers `1,0,0,1`?

For example,

```
var array = [1,0,0,1];
if (array === 1001) alert("success");
```

Comment: 1,0,1,0 will return true or only 1,0,0,1?

Comment: only `1,0,0,1`  in the same order as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Note that the `join` solution won't work for numbers > 10, for example `array=[12,34]`, numbers = `1,23,4`

Comment: @georg thanks for letting me know. Hopefully in this example, it only accepts 1 or 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just `join` the array to check

> The `join()` method joins all elements of an array (or an array-like
>   object) into a string and returns this string.

Note: You need to use `==` instead of `===` because `join` will return a string.

Like:

```js
var array = [1, 0, 0, 1];
if ( array.join("") == 1001 ) alert("success");
```

---

As per suggestion below, you can also use `===` and compare it with a string.

```js
var array = [1, 0, 0, 1];
if ( array.join("") === "1001" ) alert("success");
```

Please check more info about join: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: great thank you. This as i understand converts the array into a number?

Comment: In general I never rely on JS’s type coercion. Why not just compare the string?

Comment: Probably should always use `===`, in this case `=== "1000"`

Comment: @Gragas Incoming - no, it converts it to a string.

Comment: @GragasIncoming `==` coerces `1001` (rhs) to the string `"1001"` to compare against `"1001"` on the lhs. There is no array involved in the comparison.

Comment: i'll  return that string server-side from php with ajax and json encode so something like `if ( array.join("") === "data.phpValue" ) alert("success");`

Comment: @GragasIncoming It is always recommended to use server validation. :)

Comment: What is `data.phpValue`? The code above is a js code and not a php code?

Comment: we are just discussing `data.phpValue` comes from  `echo json_encode(['phpValue'=>"1001"]);`

Comment: the can you try `if ( array.join("") === data.phpValue ) alert("success");`? without the `"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to joins all elements of the array into a string and returns this string.

```js
var elements = [1,0,0,1];

console.log(elements.join('') === "1001");
// expected output: true
```

Comment: Just goes to show the "most correct" answer doesn't always get selected on SO. Can't believe the "typecast" answer continues to get upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method `join("")` you conver your array into a string with out the commas

Then you use the `includes("1001")` to check for the expected result

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
var array = [1,0,0,1];
var string = array.join("");
console.log(string);
if (string.includes('1001')) alert("success");
```

Comment: Have you never heard of a string of numbers?

Comment: of course, but 10010001 "includes" 1001 - it isn't exact. Get it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, everyone gave a strict answer to your question; but I figured I would add on to it a little. Assuming you want this to be a little more dynamic. This way we check subsets of the array for the string you are looking for, rather than just the entire array.

```js
Array.prototype.containsSequence = function(str, delimiter){
  
  //Determines what is seperating your nums
  delimiter = delimiter || '';
  
  //Check the sub array by splicing it, then joining it
  var checkSection = function (arr, start, end, str){
      return arr.slice(start, end).join(delimiter) === str;
  };
  
  let start = 0; //start of our sub array
  let end = str.length; //the length of the sub array
  
  //Loop through each x size of sub arrays
  while(end < this.length){
    //Check the section, if it is true it contains the string
    if(checkSection(this, start, end, str)){
      return true;
    }
    //Incriment both start and end by 1
    start++;
    end++;
  }
  
  //We dont contain the values
  return false;
};

///Test stuff
const ARRAY = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

if(ARRAY.containsSequence('456')){
  console.log('It contains the str');
}else console.log('It does not contain');
```

Comment: it is rather confusing. Keep the things simple

Comment: Hey sorry about my confusing code, I added comments if that helps.